# What do you call the revival of an obsolete word for a new meaning

Tags: terminology, word-formation

Let's say *carrot* for *a shade of orange*.

Suppose *carrot* is not used for the color and I wanted one to describe the vegetable's color. So, I revive the displaced *more* for the color. What do you call such revival?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a single term for this specific combination of operations, but this seems like multiple operations: [**learned borrowing**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/learned_borrowing) + x, where x is the usual process by which *x-coloured* was substituted with *x*.

> A word or other linguistic form borrowed from a classical language into a modern language.

See the Wiktionary category [*Learnedly borrowed terms by language*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Learnedly_borrowed_terms_by_language).

A learned borrowing could be from any classical language, not necessarily from an earlier stage or nominal ancestor of the language in question.

But in some languages, especially those that undergo a revival or tend to use neologisms instead of loanwords for new concepts, like Icelandic, French, Armenian and Hebrew, it is common.

[image]

There is also a neologism [**neosemantism**](https://www.google.am/search?q="neosemantism") and its cognates, with very limited currency.